# Fill wpf treeview with mvvm

Tags: wpf

I have a table named customer with fileds(ID,Name,Code,FatherID).
 Field (ID) and (FatherID) are connected together.

i get a list of customer in mvvm (AllCustomer )

```
      public  ViewModelList(CRMEntities crm)
    {
        var all = from h in crm.Customer
                  select h;
        AllCustomer = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(all.ToList());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Customer> AllCustomer
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

/* xml file

```
        <TreeView Name="folderTree"
     ItemsSource="{Binding AllCustomer}">

        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding AllCustomer}"
                             DataType="{x:Type cls:Customer}">

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>

            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    </TreeView>
```

i want  fill  treeview that display all of customer as the father of son  !

**Who i can fill treeview with customers , with mvvm ?**
[image: My customer Model]

Comment: It is important to know the name of the children relationship (something like `ChildCustomers`), open the Entity Framework designer, it should contain this name in the Navigation properties section.

Comment: in customer table , i have a fatherid that Refers to the ID

Comment: No only ID wont suffice. You will have to populate the children list under each `Customer`... `public class Customer { public ObservableCollection<Customer> ChildCustomers { get { return childCustomers; } } }`

Comment: my treeview could have multi stages. it seems I should create a seprate class per each child. right?

Comment: @niloo If you use Entity Framework, you will have similar diagram as in this picture: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8047386/customer%20table%20sample.PNG. There are 2 navigation properties, add to your post the information about their names in your model.

Comment: @vorrtex :Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: You didn't ask a question.  Please edit your question so you're actually asking something.  Also, what are you getting stuck on?  What have you already tried?  Please include that code too, even if it is broken.

Comment: The names `Coding` and `Coding1` don;t help a lot. You can change the names of navigation proeprties so that they will not be so confusing.

Comment: They have a relationship with the coding table

Comment: Ok, I suppose that the property `Coding1` contains the collection of child objects. So you should change your data template so: `<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Coding1}"`