# WPF with MVVM Add elements to a TreeView dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I'm doing my first bigger project with WPF and my first project with MVVM.

I want to fill a TreeView with values from a list of a self-defined class.

The part of my XAML looks similar to this:

```
<Window>
    <StackPanel>
    ...
        <TreeView>
            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem />
                <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfFoo}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="50" 
                                      Content="{Binding Bar.Description}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChosen}"/>
                            <TextBox Width="38" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                     Text="{Binding SomeText}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChosen}" />  
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
    ...
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The property at my ViewModel looks like this:

```
public List<Foo> ListOfFoo
{ 
    get { return listoffoo; }
    set 
    { 
        listoffoo = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("ListOfFoo");
    }
}
```

Foo has the properties IsChosen, Bar (which is another type with a property Description) and SomeText.

When I execute my code, I can see the TreeView with the first item shown (which has some UI elements that I left out for better reading), but the items (in my test case should be 2) are not shown.

I used the following resources:

[Fill wpf treeview with mvvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791120/fill-wpf-treeview-with-mvvm)

(Can someone tell me where the x:Type comes from? I don't have that available in my x Namespace, which is defined as follows:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a concise example of how it is done http://stackoverflow.com/a/28994128/1228 You can create a new project and paste that code in and it works. Do that, then compare it with your current project to find out what is different.

Comment: You didn't use ObservableCollection, maybe this is the issue?

Comment: Your x:Type question--that xmlns is defined in PresentationCore. Grab Telerik's JustDecompile, load the net 4.5 framework, and click on PresentationCore in the list. You can see the xmlnsdefinition for that namespace pointing to System.Windows.Markup. Here's how it's implemented https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Will thank you for your example, I'll have a look at it :-). The x:Type problem could be related to me using .NET 4.0. I'll change the project to 4.5m that could be the issue.

Comment: No, your x:Type issue (not clear what the issue is) isn't related to version. If anything, it should "just work".  If it doesn't, you've screwed up something in your references, codebehind, or xaml.  Create a fresh wpf project.  Examine each of these three in the new project, and make sure you have equivalents in yours.

Comment: Hi Wojciech and Will,
I have played around a bit with your ideas. First, I changed the List to an ObservableCollection. Then I removed the other Items (which are static, but I need them) from the TreeView and put them in another TreeView which only consists of those static items.
These two steps solved my problem. Many thanks to both of you :-)

Comment: Kind of a meta question, but related to here: Wojciech's answer helped me, but the problem was solved by his comment. I can't upvote the comment though, because I don't have the reputation :/
I'll mark his answer as the correct answer for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted to achieve something like this:

```
<Window>
    <StackPanel>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MainCollection}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding InnerCollection}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="50" 
                                  Content="{Binding Bar.Description}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChosen}"/>
                        <TextBox Width="38" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                 Text="{Binding SomeText}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChosen}" />  
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

            <TreeViewItem />
        </TreeView>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Your mistakes:

- you set `ItemTemplate` for `TreeViewItem`, but you should set `ItemTemplate` for `TreeView`
- you added `<TreeViewItem />` inside `<TreeViewItem>` instead of `<TreeView>`
- you should bind to `ItemsSource` of `TreeView` with your main collection and to `ItemsSource` of `HierarchicalDataTemplate` with collection inside each element. For example if you have:

  - Players

    - Player 1

      - Teams

        - Team 1
        - Team 2
    - Player 2

      - Teams

        - Team 1
        - Team 2

then you should set binding in `TreeView` to players list and in `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to teams list.